# self.view.frame.size.height 1004 instead of 1024

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6

The following line of code:

```
NSLog(@"%f, %f", self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
```

returns 768 * 1004 for an iPad device. I have hidden the status bar using

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
```

in the `viewDidLoad` method and have hidden the `navigationbar` in the `viewWillAppear` method using

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
```

What am I missing exactly? I believe it should be returning 1024 rather than 1004.

**Note**: The `viewcontroller` is created through the Storyboard and is of a `ModalStoryboardSegue` with a Full Screen Presentation.

Comment: Is the status bar visible in Interface Builder?

Comment: Just a guess, but you are doing it in viewDidLoad.  The view may already be locked into the 768 * 1004 dimensions.  Perhaps you should hide the statusBar in viewWillLoad?  Then perhaps the view will initialize using the full 768x1024 size when it does load.

Comment: @JohnBowers In viewDidLoad you would only have 0 * 0.

Comment: @0x7fffffff The status bar is not visible in the Interface Builder.

Comment: @grasGendarme, yes, in viewWillLoad self.view.frame.size will be 0x0 in the best case, because self.view is nil. viewWillLoad is called, as its name suggests, before the view is loaded. What John Bowers is trying to explain that the status bar, which does exist at that point, should be hidden at a point in time before self.view is beeing loaded so that it can occupy the all of the available space.

Comment: @HermannKlecker `self.view` won't be nil as we were talking about view _Did_ load

Comment: @grasGendarme, sorry, wie misunderstood each other. John was talking about viewWILLLoad and I must have thought you were talking about that too.

Comment: @HermannKlecker Woops you're right. Anyway, the OP should try to NSLog in __viewWillAppear__, and the result should be the awaited 1024 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you doing the logging? If I hide the status bar in viewDidLoad, and do the log in viewDidAppear, I get 1024.

Comment: Logging was done in viewDidLoad. Is there a reason why it is 1004 in viewDidLoad and 1024 in viewDidAppear and how does this impact the View setup?

Comment: @David, I think because the view hasn't been redrawn yet until the next turn of the run loop. Even if you set the animation to none, it still shows 1004 in viewDidLoad.

Comment: So should anything involving self.view.frame be implemented in the viewDidAppear method rather than the viewDidLoad so that I can use the 1024 value?

Comment: Yes, generally you do things involving the frame in viewDidAppear, or viewWillLayoutSubviews.

Answer (score 1):

`viewDidLoad` is called before view layout. In this method the size of your view is the one you set in your interface builder (simulated size).

The size shouldn't be a problem, the view will get the correct size soon enough (check `viewDidLayout` method).

Note you can still setup your views in `viewDidLoad` based on the controller's view size, just set your autoresizing masks correctly.